# Conversion in rails params for a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When sending params to a rails controller like from a test or a view

```
 { "a[b]" => true }
```

I receive it as

```
 {"a" => {"b" => true}}
```

I would like to know how this happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because rails middleware convert this type of parameter into hash so that it is more easy to access and use. You can have more in depth info in Rails guide.